# Angularjs loading screen with dynamic template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a directive that accepts a template name which dynamically loads the correct template.
It looks like this:

```
angular.module('widget.directives').directive('pkSplash', directive);

function directive() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'PkSplashController',
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>',
        link: lnkFn
    };

    function lnkFn(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        scope.contentUrl = 'app/directives/pkSplash-' + attrs.pkSplash + '.html';
        attrs.$observe('template', function (template) {
            scope.contentUrl = 'app/directives/pkSplash-' + template + '.html';
        });
        scope.$watch(controller.loading, function (loading) {
            controller.loaded = !loading;
        });
    };
};
```

The directive actually sits on the **index.html** page like this:

```
<div pk-splash="{{ loaderTemplate }}" ng-if="loaderTemplate"></div>
```

and the **loaderTemplate** is set on the **$rootScope** when a state change starts, like this:

```
function run($rootScope, pkSplashService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
        $rootScope.loaderTemplate = pkSplashService.getTemplate(toState.name);
        console.log($rootScope.loaderTemplate);
    });
};
```

I have put console logs on the **$stateChangeStart** method and I can see that when swapping states that the template name does change, but the loader will only ever use the template that is first loaded.
Does anyone know how I can get it to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part it looks like you are observing an attribute called 'template' but you aren't passing one:

```
    attrs.$observe('template', function (template) {
        scope.contentUrl = 'app/directives/pkSplash-' + template + '.html';
    });
```

In that case, you would need to use it like this:

```
<div pk-splash template="{{ loaderTemplate }}" ng-if="loaderTemplate"></div>
```

The other option would be to observe the pkSplash attribute instead:

```
 attrs.$observe('pkSplash', function (template) {
     scope.contentUrl = 'app/directives/pkSplash-' + template + '.html';
 });
```